# Receiving 'events is not iterable' after updating function but the document format hasn't changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loops, pagination

I updated my function to paginate my index and now I'm receiving error 'event is not iterable' from the client side code. Here's the client code that's causing the error (it's at the very top of the page and required for the entire page to display).

```
<% for (let event of events){%>
```

Remember, it was working before I changed the function so here's the code prior to my recent edits:

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
   const events = await Event.find({}).populate('artist');
   res.render('events/index', { events });
};
```

Here's the updated code:

```
module.exports.index = async (req, res) => {
    const page = parseInt(req.query.page);
    const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);

    const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
    const endIndex = page * limit;

    const events = {}

    if(endIndex < await Event.countDocuments().exec()) {
        events.next = {
            page: page + 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    if(startIndex > 0) {
        events.previous = {
            page: page - 1,
            limit: limit
        }
    }

    events.events = await Event.find().limit(limit).skip(startIndex).exec()
    res.paginatedResults = events;
    res.render('events/index', { events });
    };
```

The new function returns the array I'm looking for (when I console.log), so it *works* from a query/pagination standpoint but I'm forgetting to send something to the client side after the code runs that's tripping up the iteration.

I'm also not populating 'artists' anymore but I don't think that has anything to do with it..

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: Just means whatever `exec()` returns isn't iterable, i.e. you are trying to iterate over something that is not an array.

Comment: Thanks @vitaly-t that helps add some color. The `events` variable *is* the array that I want. If I remove the events.events query the `events` variable only contains the "previous page x, next page y" footnote data. Any idea how I could get events to properly iterate?

Comment: I dropped the query results for `events` in the configuration panel here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/n6rWMy9ttnf